# S-Lang shell (slsh): capture command output in a variable

Tags: command-substitution, s-lang

In slsh I know that I have to !-prefix a command to execute it:

```
!ls
```

How can I capture its output in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find anything in the docs about a way to do this directly, but you can create functions to do that yourself relatively easily with the help of `popen`.

If you want to grab all the output into a list of strings, you could do this:

```c
define grab_output (command)
{
    variable fp, lines;

    fp = popen (command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        throw OpenError, "Failed to popen ($command)";
    lines = fgetslines(fp);
    () = fclose (fp);
    return lines;
}
```

If you want to process each line as they're coming, then using something like this would probably be better:

```c
define display_output (command)
{
    variable fp, line;

    fp = popen (command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        throw OpenError, "Failed to popen ($command)";
    foreach line (fp) using ("line")
    {
        printf("% 5d - %s", strlen(line), line);
    }
    () = fclose (fp);
}
```

Usage:

```c
variable line;
variable lines = grab_output("/usr/bin/cal");
foreach line (lines)
{
    printf("stdout: %s", line); 
}

display_output("cat t.sl");
```

Warning: this was simply pieced together from examples in the [S-Lang guide](http://www.jedsoft.org/slang/doc/html/slang.html), I don't actually know the language.